# JS Problem with encoding decoding UTF?

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8

I'm dealing with a JSON file that i cannot modify, i have to keep it AS IS.

it contains text, with all the apostrophes converted to `‚Äô`, and other special chars here and there...

what is that? unicode? how can i convert to the regular apostrophe?

i placed already the META tag utf-8 on the header but it doesn't seem to change anything...

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html  This article really helped me.

Comment: @Macy And hey! It's by one of the SO founders

Comment: @Rudu ;) I swear I'm not a plant.

Comment: How are you loading the file?  With a `<script>` tag or some other way?

Comment: @Macy But that's something a plant would say!

Comment: @Rudu Would a plant guzzle Carbon like I do?  Oh wait...

Comment: @Macy well - as long as you're not producing [organic compounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthesis)

Answer (score 3):

What mime type is your JSON response being sent with? (Look in the headers in FireBug or the Developer Console.) It seems that you one of these steps is using a different encoding:

- The JSON string generated by the web server
- The mime type encoding sent along with the response
- The mime type of your HTML page
- The mime type for your JavaScript code

If you supply the community with actual code, or better yet a working reproducible test case, then the community can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

> what is that?

It is an attempt to interpret data stored in one character encoding as data stored in a different character encoding.

To ensure everything displays correctly you need to:

- Pick an encoding (UTF-8 is a good bet)
- Store everything in that encoding

  - Configure your editor to use it!
  - Configure your database (if applicable) to use it!
- Ensure any server side code you use expects UTF-8 input and gives UTF-8 output
- Configure your webserver to include `charset=utf-8` on the Content-Type HTTP header

The W3C has [a good introductory article](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding.en) on the subject, which has links to lots of useful further reading at the end.